# Remove Silence from an Audio Input and then find the frequencies of the remaining audio signal using numpy in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, audio

I have a Audio Signal and have imported using `wave.open` function.
then I am converting the signal into frames and then using a window to take a set number of samples and checking their amplitude to see if it falls within a set threshold. If it does then I consider it as a Silence and if not then and Audio Signal.

```
import wave
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

sound_file = wave.open('Audio_1.wav', 'r') 
file_length = sound_file.getnframes()
sound = np.zeros(file_length)
for i in range(file_length):
    data = sound_file.readframes(1)
    data = struct.unpack("<h", data)
    sound[i] = int(data[0])
sound = np.divide(sound, float(2**15)) # Normalized data range [-1 to 1]
#print sound #vector corresponding to  audio signal containing audio samples
Ap = np.pad(sound, (0,int(np.ceil(len(sound) / 2205.)) * 2205 - len(sound)), 'constant', constant_values=0) # Padding of the sound samples so that the input is a multiple of 2205(window Length)
Apr = Ap.reshape((len(Ap) // 2205, 2205)) 
Apr.shape
array1=(Apr ** 2).sum(axis=1) #Record Sum of Squares of the amplitude of  the signal  falling within that window
print array1
#print len(array1)
threshold =1103.4
result= np.array(filter(lambda x: x>= threshold, array1)) #filtering elements below set threshold
print result 

print len(result)
print np.where(array1>1103.4) # finding starting index of the elements.
```

Below are my doubts:

1. How to find the ending index of the window? So that I can specifically slice that window out from the input.
2. How should I proceed so that I can get back the samples which contain the audio signal and convert those signals into frequency domain using `np.fft.fft()`.

If any statement or question unclear. Please Specify.
Thank you

Comment: You can take a look on http://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/